# MySql Event not working

Tags: mysql

I have the following script written for event schedule. This is my first time with schedule. I am not getting any errors but it doesn't perform the required operation.

```
  CREATE EVENT checkBlack  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND DO 
  DELETE FROM BlackList WHERE id=13;
```

It displays this message `<n>Query: Create EVENT checkBlack2 on Schedule every 5 second DO Delete from BlackList where id=13
0 row(s) affected`

But I have a row with id 13.

Help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE  /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/ EVENT `checkBlack`

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
DO
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `BlackList` WHERE id=13;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```